# How to change text on the screen in a loop until user acts

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I would like to build an activity, which displays a set of strings in a loop until the user clicks on the screen.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to do this in Kotlin, but Java advice is also welcomed.

I have built an activity with TextSwitcher and a variable (isClicked) that indicates whether the user has clicked on the screen. I set up a listener that sets the isClicked when user clicks. Then in a loop I check the value of isClicked and if it is not checked I change the value of the text.

```
class SelectionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var isClicked = true
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.selection)
        val textSwitcher = findViewById<TextSwitcher>(R.id.selectionText)
        textSwitcher.setFactory {
            val textView = TextView(this)
            textView.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
            textView.textSize = 32f
            textView
        }
        textSwitcher.setCurrentText("Start")

        textSwitcher.setOnClickListener {
            isClicked = false;
        }

        var i = 0;
        while (isClicked) {
            textSwitcher.setText(i.toString())
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This does not seem to work. The app just hangs and becomes non-responsive. If I understand correctly, it might have something to do with activity class being in the UI thread and while loop being too heavy for it. However, I am not sure how this should be solved.

Comment: The app will hang because you are forcing it to stay inside a loop. Apps have their own internal loop to listen for event that you shouldn't  mess with.

Comment: Here you can find how to handle events. Please use the standard mechanism and do not create a loop for this purpose. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/input-events

Comment: I do exactly that. I attach the listener to the element. But the problem is not in registering the event, but in getting the text changed. I expect to see a constantly changing text on TextSwitcher, but that does not happen.

Comment: Could you edit your question and post your code? If you have a loop, you need to remove it. There is no reason to use a loop to get user events.

Comment: Added the code. Really appreciate the guidance.

I am not getting the user events in the loop. I am trying to change the TextSwitcher value in the loop.

Comment: Let me understand the expected behavior. The textSwitcher should change its value until the user clicks?

Comment: Yes, this is the desired behavior. Currently, when I get to this activity everything just becomes unresponsive.